# Renamed a table to sp_help and cannot rename it back

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Somehow one of our tables was accidentally renamed to 'sp_help'.

We have tried to rename it back to the previous table name using sp_rename but we are getting the following error:

```
Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 332
No item by the name of 'MyDatabase.dbo.sp_help' could be found in the current database 'MyDatabase', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.
```

We have also tried to rename it directly in management studio with the same error. Is there any other way of renaming this table back to the previous name?

Comment: Sounds to me like it got put in a different schema other than `dbo`.

Comment: You can drop the table and recreate it but the data will of course be lost if you don't have a backup somewhere. `drop table sp_help` works.

Comment: I have checked in sys.objects and it is definitely in the dbo schema.

Comment: Locate the renamed object in the database and check for the full name of the object-- databasename.schema.object_name.

Comment: I think you're doomed. The problem is, the `sp_` prefix causes name lookup to be re-directed to the `master` database in preference to actually looking in any database and/or schema that you specify. It may be possible to directly update the system tables via the [DAC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.90).aspx) but at this point I'd never trust this database again. Restore from a backup from before the rename and learn from the experience?

Comment: (Even more dangerous approach that wouldn't need DAC and direct fiddling would be to rename `sp_help` in the master database and then attempt to rename the table in your DB. In that case, the weird `sp_` name lookup should find your table and then you can go and fix the real `sp_help`. But if I did that, I'd no longer trust the instance, rather than just the DB)

Comment: Maybe he can restore the database to a throwaway instance before fixing it this way to regain the data in the table.

Comment: In that case is there a way of doing a select query based off an object id? That way we can at least get the data back again.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `sp_help` is in the resource database and can't be renamed.

Comment: @MartinSmith - ah, true. For some reason, that bit of info never sticks and my thinking about the system procedures is still back in the 2000 era.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ALTER the metadata of the dbo.sp_help object and perform a SWITCH.

Here's a test case that should get you started:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t_Foo
(
    Bar         BIT
);
GO

EXECUTE dbo.sp_rename @objname = 'dbo.t_Foo', @newname = 'sp_help';
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.t_Foo
(
    Bar         BIT
);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sp_help]
SWITCH TO dbo.t_Foo;
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.t_Foo;
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[sp_help]
GO
```

Comment: +1 Works fine. Without messing around with the DAC and system tables.

Comment: Could you help my poor brain understand *how* this works? I've read the [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) related to `SWITCH` but to no avail

Comment: I _believe_ only DML statements will actually attempt to find `sp_` prefixed objects in the master catalog, so the DDL `ALTER` succeeds as the `DROP` did.  I unfortunately have thus far been unable to furnish any supporting documentation or otherwise prove this.